# How do I wire multiple switches for my bathroom lights and fan?

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, bathroom, bathroom-fixtures

I am redoing a bathroom and onto my wiring. I am installing (4) recessed lights, (1) fan, and three switches.

I want one switch to control (2) recessed lights, the next switch to control the other (2) recessed lights, and the third switch to control the fan.

I currently have one wire coming up from the main breaker box (hot,common, ground) and would ideally hit the switch first before I went into the attic.

What is the best way to wire this type of setup? I have only done basic wiring (one fixture/one switch) and wanted to get some advice.

** Side note (4" and 5" recessed lights, IC rated, normal line voltage, and the fan draws 12 watts).*

---

[Update from OP]

A diagram would be absolutely great! Unfortunately I really need this broken down to me dummy style.

I am definitely never going to be an artist, but here is a quick drawing. Just note one thing, I can put the fan outlet on the same side as the light 2 gang box.

[image]

Comment: Do you want to run the wire to the fan directly from the switch box, or from the lights first? And do you want to run all the lights as a chain, or run two separate cables from the switch box to the lights?

Comment: I have full access so I can really run it however I'd like. I would prefer just to go to the switch first since it comes from bottom floor up through bathroom then will go up to attic for wiring the lights and fan. I am up for doing it anyway that is recommended.

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri -- you only need 12/2 for that

Comment: Could you add a sketch of the room including lights, fan, and switch locations?

Comment: Oh and by the way, how do the bathroom receptacles play into this? Are they on their own circuit, or...?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel: Oops thank you.Reposting comment.

Comment: I am convinced that straightforward is best here. Power to the switch gang box, run three 12/2 cables up to the attic. One cable to the fan, another cable to a light with a second cable continuing to another light, and the third cable to a light with another cable continuing to the last light. Use pigtails where needed instead of putting more than one wire on any screw terminal, and if the switches have backstabs, don't use them. Would you like a wiring diagram?

Comment: A diagram would be absolutely great! Unfortunately I really need this broken down to me dummy style.

I am definitely never going to be an artist, but here is a quick drawing. Just note one thing, I can put the fan outlet on the same side as the light 2 gang box.

Thanks for all the help!!

Comment: Believe one bathroom outlet is on a separate circuit. I can double check that tomorrow.

Answer (score 6):

If I understand your layout, you could wire it like this:

[image: SUGGESTED BATHROOM WIRING]

Chaining to all four lights like this requires the use of 12/3 cable for the first two sections, but if you want to follow Tester101's suggestion and add the extra conductor to the fan circuit for possible future use, you're going to buy some 12/3 anyway.

EDIT: Carl Witthoft is correct, the bathroom should be protected by a GFCI. I have altered my diagram to show a GFCI outlet with downstream protection.

EDIT: For Brent Self. The white wires carry the neutral, the black wires carry constant-hot and switched-hot, and the red wires are all switched-hot. Wires that end at a load are switched-hot. The other black wires are constant-hot.

Fault ground wires are not shown in this diagram. Fault ground wiring is extremely simple: at every switch, lighting fixture, fan, and junction box, all the ground wires are connected together. Also, every metal junction box should be connected to the fault ground. Also, where possible, every metal fixture or load part that a user might touch should be connected to the fault ground.

Comment: This is based on a description in an earlier version of Tester101's answer, modified in light of your pen sketch.

Comment: NOte that code in most places (in the US, at least), require a GFCI unit for wiring in a 'wet' (bathroom, kitchen) room.  That GFCI needs to be between the hot feed and everything receiving power in the bathroom.

Comment: @Carl Witthoft is correct, I should have included the GFCI outlet. Fixed. - Experienced electricians note, I have no practical experience yet using GFCIs, please check my GFCI wiring.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Can you point to the code section that requires lights in a bathroom to be GFCI protected?

Comment: @Tester101 If the lights are on a completely separate circuit maybe not.  I admit to not being an expert on current code.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the new information, here's one way to do it.

[image]
<sup>*Power to light switch box*</sup>

This assumes power enters at the light switch box. If power enters at the fan switch box, the wiring will be similar enough that you should have no trouble figuring it out.

[image]
<sup>*Power to fan switch box*</sup>

For the cable between the switch and the fan, you can install a three wire cable instead of a two wire cable. Though you don't need the third wire now, it will allow you to easily install a combo device in the future (fan/light, fan/heat, etc.).